# JaCoCo instrumentation at runtime without reflection

Tags: java, jacoco

I am trying to use JaCoCo to measure the code coverage of a `model` class, after running a method which generates random tests which call methods of the `model` class. Essentially, the structure looks like this:

`main -> testRunner -> model`

In main, I want to instrument the `model` class and generate code coverage information using JaCoCo. I can instrument the model in main or testRunner as follows:

```
final String targetName = model.class.getName();
final IRuntime runtime = new LoggerRuntime();

final Instrumenter instr = new Instrumenter(runtime);
JaCoCoHelper jaCoCoHelper = new JaCoCoHelper();
InputStream original = getTargetClass(targetName);

byte[] instrumented = null;
instrumented = instr.instrument(original, targetName);
original.close();

final RuntimeData data = new RuntimeData();
runtime.startup(data);

final JaCoCoHelper.MemoryClassLoader memoryClassLoader = new JaCoCoHelper.MemoryClassLoader();
memoryClassLoader.addDefinition(targetName, instrumented);
targetClass = memoryClassLoader.loadClass(targetName);
```

But the issue is that after instrumenting the model class, I get a different copy of the class, `targetClass`. It is my understanding that for the JaCoCo code coverage to work, I need to instantiate an object of this `targetClass` and make all calls from there. However, the problem with that is since this class is not present at compile time, Java doesn't know about its methods, fields etc and can't type check the rest of the code, so I will have to resort Java reflection and typecasting everything appropriately. How can I instrument the class and also have Java type check the rest of the code?

Is there some way to instrument the `testRunner` from `main` and have JaCoCo recursively instrument all classes used from testRunner, or perhaps instrument the `model` class and have that replace the `model` class in `testRunner`, in a way that at compile time I can still call the `model` class so that Java knows how to type check it?